# ng-model in ng-repeat become undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, undefined-behavior

Using Javascript with angularJs, I kind the following code :

**JS**

```
 $scope.myObj = {
     'sthg': '',
     'a': [{
          'b' : ''
     }]
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<p ng-repeat="radio in fiche.radios">
    <input type="text" ng-model="radio.code" placeholder="Numéro de cliché" ng-required="true" />
    <span >
      <button type="button"ng-click="removeRadioList($index);" ng-disabled="fiche.radios.length === 1">
        <i>X</i>
      </button>
    </span>
  </p>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/LOgk7Nudse0srS7Bs1G6?p=preview

In my App `$scope.myObj.a[0].b` is undefined with the ng-repeat (if I remove ng-repeat, it will be defined). 
In the plunkr it is defined even after the run of ng-repeat, but I managed to have the behaviour when I enter something in the input and then delete it.

I don't get what's hapening, I would like to understand why and if it is a good way to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beacause you set `ng-required="true"` on your input tag angular wouldn't bind empty value to your model thous when you delete value from input your console shows you `radios.code` as undefined.

Please see below for working demo:

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";

  var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
 
  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $log) {
    $scope.ficheInit = {
      'user_id': '',
      'radios': [{
        'code': ''
      }]
    };
    $log.log($scope.ficheInit);
    $scope.fiche = angular.copy($scope.ficheInit);
    $log.log($scope.fiche);
    $scope.addRadioList = function() {
      $scope.fiche.radios.push({
        'code': ''
      });
    }
    $scope.removeRadioList = function(i) {
      $scope.fiche.radios.splice(i, 1);
    }
    $scope.disableAddRadio = function() {
      console.log($scope.fiche.radios);
      return !(angular.isDefined($scope.fiche.radios[$scope.fiche.radios.length - 1].code) || $scope.fiche.radios.length < 1);
    }

  });

}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="plunker">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <button ng-click="showForm=true;">SHOW</button>
    <div ng-show="showForm">
      <button ng-click="addRadioList();" ng-disabled="disableAddRadio()">Ajouter un cliché</button>
      <p ng-repeat="radio in fiche.radios">
        <input type="text" ng-model="radio.code" placeholder="Numéro de cliché" />
        <span>
          <button type="button" ng-click="removeRadioList($index);" ng-disabled="fiche.radios.length === 1">
            <i>X</i>
          </button>
        </span>
      </p>
    </div>
    {{fiche.radios}}
  </div>
</div>
```